# Android - Call a function when authenticate process end

Tags: android, dropbox, oncreate

I'm trying to integrate dropbox upload in my app. I've read the official examples and I was able to write a client to upload the files.
Now there is just one thing that I'd like to fix..
the example first run this line of code:

```
mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MainActivity.this);
```

and then use OnResume to complete the auth:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            // Required to complete auth, sets the access token on the session
            mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

            String accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
        }
    }
    new myOperation().execute("");
}
```

This works, but I was looking for a way to replace the onResume (that is also called when the app start and cause some exceptions). Is there a way to call a function when the         mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MainActivity.this); ends ?

Thanks for the help, and as usual, if you need further infos please ask

Comment: See also https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=115538 on the Dropbox API forum.

Comment: I was the author of that post..

Comment: Yes, I know. I posted links on each question to the other to avoid duplicate work by those helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is the only way available by the API, then you have to use it
if you have a control over what startOAuth2Authentication do, you can use *startActivityForResult()* , but its inside API you can't change it.

so i would suggest you handle whatever exceptions you get at *onResume()*
by using some validations, like wrapping whole code inside *onResume()* with this

```
if(mDBApi!=null){...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is also that I've to use this from another class (that doesn't extend activity), are you sure that there isn't any way to use startActivityForResult ??

Comment: i think yes, there is no way, because startActivityForResult  involves 2 parts, starter to use startActivityForResult , and target activity to setResult(RESULT_OK,..); finish(); so u need to set this in the method startOAuth2Authentication () which u dont have access to, if you make a new activity that u start it ForResult, and in that activity u do the startOAuth2Authentication , onResume for that activity setResult(RESULT_OK,..); finish(); BUT you will end with the same issue, onResume might crash.

Comment: That's very problematic for me, as I need to integrate that uploader on another class that doesn't extend activity..... Damn, I've to look for another solution... Well, if nobody comes with a new idea, I'll mark your answer as accepted.